# Search with "grep" for folder names

Tags: bash, shell, search, grep

When using grep you can search for a specific regex, but only inside of a file.
Is there any way, I can search for a folder name?

Answer (score 24):

I usually use find:

```
$ find . -name 'FolderBasename*' -type d
```

or for more complex queries

```
$ find . -regex '{FolderRegex}' -type d
```

As pointed out in the comments if you want case insensitive searches do -iname and -iregex

Comment: `-name` doesn't take a regular expression.  If you need to match with a regular expression, you probably want `-regex` or `-iregex`

Comment: @Mark You're right - my bad there. I usually only need the supported * and ? (see [man find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find)) to get things found.

Comment: Could you also elaborate on the options. It's an easy online search, but I would still like to know.

Answer (score 7):

If you really mean regexp instead of shellglob, you may want to use

`find <path> -regex <regex> -type d`

eg.

`find Code/ -E -regex '(bin|redblack)_tree\.hs' -type d`

the option `-E` turns on extendend regexp, see `man find` for more.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just concerned with matching the name you can simply use '**-name**' in find.

```
find <path> -name '<regex>' -type d
```

Answer (score 2):

find is far better but a clunky answer to your question:

```
ls -l | grep '^d'
```

Comment: technically is the only one that *actually* answered the question as written, even if not as intended. However, it's limited to the folder you're in. May want to adjust so it's recursive with the -R flag on ls.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer, which works without using regex (and Bash4: `shopt -s globstar`):

```
ls **/dirname/ -d
```

(based on recursive globbing: `**/` and matching only folders `/*/`)

Answer (score 0):

I created a script file called dsearch (directory search) to do this:

```
# !/bin/bash
# search all folders from the current folder for a foldername
foldername=$1
find . -name "*$foldername*" -type d
```